# StrongLoop Loopback example in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, loopbackjs

I'm trying to implement the example LoopBack iOS app in Swift

[Create a LoopBack iOS app: part one](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/DOC/Creating+a+LoopBack+iOS+app%3a+part+one)

and I'm having some trouble translating from the ObjectiveC

```
- (void) getBooks
{
    //Error Block
    void (^loadErrorBlock)(NSError *) = ^(NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Error on load %@", error.description);
    };
    void (^loadSuccessBlock)(NSArray *) = ^(NSArray *models){
        NSLog(@"Success count %d", models.count);
        self.tableData = models;
        [self.myTable reloadData];
    };
    //This line gets the Loopback model "book" through the adapter defined in AppDelegate
    LBModelRepository *allbooks = [[booksAppDelegate adapter] repositoryWithModelName:prototypeName];
    //Logic - Get all books. If connection fails, load the error block, if it passes, call the success block and pass allbooks to it.
    [allbooks allWithSuccess:loadSuccessBlock  failure:loadErrorBlock];
};
```

Here's my version

```
func getBooks() {
    var errorBlock = {
        (error: NSError!) -> Void in
        NSLog("Error on load %@", error.description)
    }

    var successBlock = {
        (models: NSArray!) -> Void in
        NSLog("Success count %d", models.count)
        self.tableData = models
        self.booksTable.reloadData()
    }

    // get the "book" model
    var allBooks: LBModelRepository = adapter.repositoryWithModelName(prototypeName)

    // get all books
    allBooks.allWithSuccess(successBlock, errorBlock)
}
```

but I get a compiler error on the call to allWithSuccess:

Cannot convert the expressions type 'Void' to type 'LBModelAllSuccessBlock!'

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:**

If I declare the success block as follows, it works:

```
    var successBlock = {
        (models: AnyObject[]!) -> () in
        self.tableData = models
        self.booksTable.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: try defining your `var`s as functions with the `func` keyword like: `func errorBlock () { }`

Comment: You may want to checkout this swift example I created: https://github.com/kgoedecke/loopback-swift-user-example

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer!!!!

If anyone is looking for the last version of Swift and LoopBack iOS SDK, it worked for me like this:

```
func getBooks() {
    // Error Block
    let errorBlock = {
        (error: NSError!) -> Void in
        NSLog("Error on load %@", error.description)
    }

    // Success Block
    let successBlock = {
        (models: [AnyObject]!) -> () in
        self.tableData = models
        self.myTable.reloadData()
    }

    // This line gets the Loopback model "book" through the adapter defined in AppDelegate
    let allBooks:LBPersistedModelRepository = AppDelegate.adapter.repositoryWithModelName(prototypeName, persisted: true) as! LBPersistedModelRepository

    // Logic - Get all books. If connection fails, load the error block, if it passes, call the success block and pass allbooks to it.
    allBooks.allWithSuccess(successBlock, failure: errorBlock)
}
```