# Strongloop's loopback iOS client SDK in Apple swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, loopbackjs

I tried to use the SDK in Apple's new swift programming language by bridging to OC. I couldn't call "LBRESTAdapter adapterWithURL". Seems like some .h files are missing.

Did anyone try the SDK with swift so far?

Comment: This should help you: http://kevingoedecke.me/2015/12/11/using-loopback-ios-sdk-with-cocoapods-in-swift/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We at StrongLoop haven't tried the SDK with Swift yet, but some folks in the community have tried it. Please post this question here. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/loopbackjs

See also - [StrongLoop Loopback example in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268398/strongloop-loopback-example-in-swift)